# Using SFINAE to resolve allocator member conditionally

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I am writing a constructor for a list data structure.

```
template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class list {

...
}
```

The class takes an `Allocator` template parameter and defaults to `std::allocator` if none is provided. Since C++11 allocators may have state the default constructor also takes an allocator object.

```
//    *** CONSTRUCTORS ***
explicit list(const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()): alloc_(alloc), head_(nullptr), tail_(nullptr), size_(0) {
    if(std::is_same<Allocator, customAllocator<T>>::value) {
        std::cout << "****" << std::endl;
        std::cout << alloc.member_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << alloc_.member_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "****" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When a custom allocator that contains 'member_' is provided the following lines execute without failure.

However when a `std::allocator` is passed the compiler understandably complains that there is no member '`member_`' in the allocator.

**However is there a way so that the `std::cout` lines are printed when a custom allocator is provided and not printed when the `std::allocator` (or any allocator without '`member_`') is provided?**

Thank you

Comment: With C++17 you have [`constexpr-if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) which does this. In older versions you would have to call overloaded functions, where just one of them try to display the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a typical problem for which in C++17 was introduced `if constexpr`

```
 if constexpr (std::is_same<Allocator, customAllocator<T>>::value) {
    std::cout << "****" << std::endl;
    std::cout << alloc.member_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << alloc_.member_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << "****" << std::endl;
}
```

Before C++17, `if constexpr` isn't available so `std::cout << alloc.member_` is compiled also when the `std::is_same` test is false.

So you have to develop, in some way, two different functions: one for `customAllocator` and one for others.

I suppose you can try something as follows (caution:code not tested)

```
   template <typename T>
   void printMember (customAllocator<T> const & a)
    { 
      std::cout << "****" << std::endl;
      std::cout << alloc.member_ << std::endl;
      std::cout << alloc_.member_ << std::endl;
      std::cout << "****" << std::endl;
    }

   template <typename A>
   void printMember (A const &)
    { }

   explicit list(const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
      : alloc_(alloc), head_(nullptr), tail_(nullptr), size_(0)
    { printMember(alloc); }
```

If you want, you can also write a function for allocators with `member_` member and one for others.

Something as follows (caution: code not tested)

```
   template <typename A>
   auto printMember (A const & a, int)
      -> decltype( a.member_, void() )
    { 
      std::cout << "****" << std::endl;
      std::cout << alloc.member_ << std::endl;
      std::cout << alloc_.member_ << std::endl;
      std::cout << "****" << std::endl;
    }

   template <typename A>
   void printMember (A const &, long)
    { }

   explicit list(const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
      : alloc_(alloc), head_(nullptr), tail_(nullptr), size_(0)
    { printMember(alloc, 0); }
```

Comment: `if constexpr` can be simulated in C++14 (for example: https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2015/07/simulate-static_if-with-c11c14.html)